# Two methods look like they are doing the same thing but give different output. Why?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, integer, conditional-statements

Two methods look like they are doing the same thing but give different output. Why?

Inputs:

```
-6
1
-5
```

Method 1:

```
public void setGoalkeepingSkill(int goalkeepingSkill) {
    if (goalkeepingSkill > 5 && goalkeepingSkill < 1) {
        System.out.println("invalid skill value goalkeeping");
        this.goalkeepingSkill = 1;
    } else {
        this.goalkeepingSkill = goalkeepingSkill; 
        System.out.println("Goalkeeping Skill has been set");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Goalkeeping Skill has been set
Goalkeeping Skill has been set
Goalkeeping Skill has been set
```

Method 2:

```
public void setGoalkeepingSkill(int goalkeepingSkill) {

    if(goalkeepingSkill<=5 && goalkeepingSkill>=1){
        this.goalkeepingSkill = goalkeepingSkill;
        System.out.println("Goalkeeping Skill has been set");
    }else{
        this.goalkeepingSkill=1;
        System.out.println("invalid skill value goalkeeping");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
invalid skill value goalkeeping
Goalkeeping Skill has been set
invalid skill value goalkeeping
```

EDIT: I thought || denotes AND, && denotes OR. My bad

Comment: Take a look at [De Morgan Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: Hint: there is no integer that is BOTH greater than 5 AND less than 1 at the same time.  But that is what the `if` condition requires in the first version of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method, the conditon `goalkeepingSkill > 5 && goalkeepingSkill < 1` is always false. No number can be both greater than 5 and less than 1. If you want to inverse the condition of the second method, you need to use the `||` logical operator instead of `&&`:

```java
public void setGoalkeepingSkill(int goalkeepingSkill) {
    if (goalkeepingSkill > 5 || goalkeepingSkill < 1) {
        // Here -------------^
        System.out.println("invalid skill value goalkeeping");
        this.goalkeepingSkill = 1;
    } else {
        this.goalkeepingSkill = goalkeepingSkill; 
        System.out.println("Goalkeeping Skill has been set");
    }
}
```